# Output a string on a variable in Bash scripting?

Tags: bash

I am trying to output a string on my variables:

```
var1="$1"
var2="$2"
email_subject="$3" 

echo "Email Message $var1  Email Message $var2" | mail -s $email_subject mail@test.com
```

Ok, I would like my three variables to have dynamic string outputs—meaning I can write whatever I want on those outputs.

I want my output to be—dynamic "this is my output", what value would I assign to my variable.

I am trying to check how variables are being assigned in Bash:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm

But it doesn't seem to show in this article.

Any assistance would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: that's how it's done.  Perhaps you want to double quote email_subject as well.  Whatever you assign to these 3 variables will be substituted in the echo statement.  Not clear what the issue is...

Comment: The issue is when I am inputting multiple string values it doesn't work.

Comment: My input is: this is my input—it doesn't work.

Comment: When I input multiple string values—this is my string—it only outputs the first word.

Comment: I am trying to have a fully automated email sending script—however, there are variables that I need such as the "Subject" and two other variables inside the message body. The rest of the content are constant.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Actually, it's not getting any error messages, thus debug is not needed at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Is double quote the problem, one alternative is to escape them

```
$ var="dynamic \"this is my output\""
$ echo "$var"
dynamic "this is my output"
```

Comment: I have mine in double quotes:

Comment: what is it that you want your code to do?  Please update your original post instead of writing comments here.